Is it possible to bundle transactions into one?
lets say, as a example, I have 10 Solana wallets, each with their own amounts of USDC. I have another Solana wallet with SOL, for fees.
Is it possible, to get all 10 USDC wallets to send all their USDC to another wallet, and have the feepayer cover the fees? Is this something that Solana can do? A bit like how BTC can use multiple UTXOs and combine them, can this be done with Solana?

yes, this is possible,
You can create a transfer ix for each of the addresses and send them in a single transaction.
async function transferTokens() {
    const signer = web3UserKeypair;
    const destination = web3DevKeypair; // ! for demo, 
    const mint = new PublicKey("AqX2zCZh6D7ytUeG5XssUbCBA1CxeGNYvHtRKg2CAazW"); // ! update with usdc mint

    const sourceTokenAcc = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        signer.publicKey
    );

    const destinationArr = new Array(10).fill(destination.publicKey); // ! update with addresses

    let transferIxs: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
    destinationArr.forEach(async (destination) => {
        const destinationAcc = await (
            await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
                connection,
                signer,
                mint,
                destination
            )
        ).address;

        const transferIx = createTransferInstruction(
            sourceTokenAcc,
            destinationAcc,
            signer.publicKey,
            1
        );

        transferIxs.push(transferIx);
    });

    const tx = new Transaction().add(...transferIxs);

    sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [signer]);
}

transferTokens();

In the snippet above, the signer is paying for all tx and account creation costs.
